# Piping stdout to stdin in perl between multiple functions (like cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 in shell)

Tags: perl, unix, pipe

I need to process large streams of data. Streams larger than would fit in RAM.

The stream needs to have multiple transformations applied to it in sequence. A pipeline of asynchronously executing tasks communicating with each other would work well, much like the following shell pipeline:

```sh
producer | transform1 | transform1 | transform2 | consumer
```

Some of these transformations are best achieved by command-line utilities which accept input from STDIN and produce their output to STDOUT.

But some of these transformations would be simple to write in Perl. I'd like to avoid having to manage a number of tiny scripts, so I'd like for them to be handled by Perl subs in the program that launches the pipeline. These subs need to be run in child processes, read from STDIN and write to STDOUT, just like the other tasks in this pipeline. This means I can't just use `system`.

How do I achieve this pipeline in Perl?

Comment: I fail to see the point in trying to emulate bash inside Perl.

Comment: @TLP I am not trying to emulate Bash inside Perl. I want to emulate a shell construct inside Perl. The functions are not shell functions, but Perl functions.

Comment: Call it what you will, I fail to see the point in connecting STDIN and STDOUT for Perl subroutines. Is there a value in this, besides just being a fun thing to do? Give me an example of a practical application.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe with threads?

Comment: @TLP Try processing data that is larger than RAM.

Comment: @OleTange So you think that by using pipes, data shrinks to fit RAM? I highly doubt that is the case. Pipes are not parallel-processing data, a program fills a data buffer to the pipe -- holds it in memory, RAM -- and the next process reads from it. The process might be optimized in different ways in the OS, but just using pipes is surely no magical solution to get around RAM issues. Do you have a specific problem to solve, because that might actually be interesting to hear about.

Comment: I see you added some more information, that is good. But unfortunately does not help to solve your problem. Where does the data come from? What do you do with it? How much data in bytes? Oh, and for future reference, what you are doing here is called [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/162416), asking a strange question about X, when your problem is really about Y, something else.

Comment: @TLP "So you think that by using pipes, data shrinks to fit RAM?" Please so not attribute any opinion to me. You can ask if I think that, and I do not. E.g. `perl -pe 's/a/b/'` will process an infinite amount of data as long as a single line will fit in RAM. And no: This is not an XY-problem: We are trying to solve a general problem, so that it is not limited to a specific kind of data. As you can see I have found a solution, so I am really just looking for *better* solutions.

Comment: @OleTange Well, this is an XY-problem, sorry to disagree with you, but your main problem is to handle large amounts of data without running out of RAM. There are ways to deal with large data, and you would get better answers asking about that, than you would asking about this business with pipes and STDIN. I hope you do, because that sounds interesting. You are not the first person to have issues with RAM.

Comment: @OleTange Also, you are clearly not looking for *better* solutions. You are looking for better versions of your own solution. Hence, XY-problem. You would be surprised how hard-headed people can be in maintaining their own view. A while ago I had to almost get into an argument with a person until s/he answered my questions. After which I solved the issue in 10 seconds. Now, I know Perl very well, and I seriously doubt that your problem needs special, custom written code to solve it. Blue pill or red pill, Ole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```perl
# This is the function to do the work
sub pipefunc {
    my $func = pop;

    my $pid = open(my $kid_to_read, "-|");
    defined($pid) || die "can't fork: $!";
    if ($pid) {
        open STDIN, "<&", $kid_to_read or die;
        &$func();
    } else { # child
        close $kid_to_read;
        if($_[1]) {
            # More than one function remaining: Recurse
            pipefunc(@_);
        } else {
            # Only one function remaining: Run it
            $func = pop;
            &$func();
        }
        exit 0;
    }
}

sub func1 {
    # Run some UNIX filter, that reads STDIN and prints to STDOUT
    while(<STDIN>) {
        print "foo $_";
    }
}

sub func2 {
    # Run some UNIX filter, that reads STDIN and prints to STDOUT
    while (<STDIN>) {
        print "bar $_";
    }
}

sub func3 {
    # Run some UNIX filter, that reads STDIN and prints to STDOUT
    exec q{perl -pe 's/o/e/g; s/a/i/g;'};
}

sub func4 {
    # Run some UNIX filter, that reads STDIN and prints to STDOUT
    exec q{perl -pe 's/^/A/g; s/$/B/g;'};
}

# This is how you use it.
# func4 | func2 | func1 | func3 | func2 | func4
pipefunc(\&func4,\&func2,\&func1,\&func3,\&func2,\&func4);
```

Try:

```
seq 10 | perl pipefunc.pl
```

Just like a pipe in shell this will work fine on input that is larger than the virtual memory on the system. Just like a pipe in shell it will run a process for each function.

Using `system` it is easy to mix perl functions with shell commands, so by wrapping the shell command in `sub myfunc { system "shell command"; }` you can get the effect of: `perlfunc | shell command | perlfunc | perlfunc | shell command`.

Answer (score 2):

Have `myfunc1`, `myfunc2`, and `myfunc3` accept input as arguments to the subroutine and return the output as the subs' return value. That is, change

```
sub myfunc1 {
    while (<STDIN>) {
        do something
        print STDOUT $_;
    }
}
```

to something like

```
sub myfunc1 {
    return map {
        do something;
        $_
    } @_;
}
```

Then you can chain your functions like:

```
print STDOUT myfunc3(myfunc2(myfunc1(<STDIN>)));
```

Comment: This will not work: If STDIN is bigger than the largest harddisk, it will not work. Instead please assume the functions read from STDIN and write to STDOUT, and that you cannot change these functions.

Answer (score 2):

The [`IPC::Run`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) package will do this for you.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use IPC::Run qw(run);

my @cat = qw(cat);
my @wc = qw(wc -l);

run @cat, '|', \@wc;
```

Comment: Can you show how to use IPC::Run with 3 perl functions - not shell commands. You can assume they are called func1, func2, func3.

Comment: @Ole Tange That only makes sense if different tasks (thread, process, coro) run each function. Which one are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: I am currently using https://stackoverflow.com/a/71514736/363028 which does exactly what I am looking for, but I would love something prettier.